# Skip migration instead of raising error when concurrent migration detected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a K8S cluster, we have several container running our rails apps.

When we deploy / update image of an app, all of the container will run

```
rails db:migrate
```

On rails 5 or later, it will raise an error (which is great). But, it will cause the container to fails and making the deployment to recreates the containers.

How can we avoid the error, and silently skips the migration when concurrent migration detected?

Comment: That's a bad idea. You should only run migrate on one container or separately before deploying the others. If you skip a migration while it's running on another container might cause your migrations to run out of order (updating tables that don't exist yet) or deploy finishing and new code running without required tables/columns.

Comment: @SiimLiiser isn't rails already lock the database when they started migrating?
Maybe i should update the question better. I'm not looking for parallel migration.
If i notice correctly, Rails will raise error on later container spawned, not the first one. The first one will continue to do the migration. Hence, it will cause the pod detects failure and restart the pod. If the later container not raising error. the pod wont detect failure and continue working just fine.